# (laravel 4) Updating profile info // display empty value or the value already stored in the table?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel-4, user-profile

So here is the thing,
I am using Laravel 4, I have a user profile update page for them to update their profile. When a user is created nothing is done to other tables like addresses, cities, countries, gender. Meaning, he only appears in the user table. Now when he update his profile entries are supposed to be created for this user in those tables.

Here is my problem, I am trying to show in the input field the value that is stored in the database. It works fine ONLY if the user has an entry in every tables, otherwise it doesn’t because the $address->addressline1 is a non object….

Here is the controller code to show the update page:

```
    public function getProfileUpdate() {

        $user       = User::where('id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
        $countries  = Country::all();


        if ($user->count()) {
            $user       = $user->first();

            $address    = Address::where('id', '=', $user->address_id);

            if ($address->count()) {
                $address    = $address->first();
                $city       = City::where('id', '=', $address->city_id);

                if ($city->count()) {
                    $city           = $city->first();
                    $country        = Country::where('id', '=', $city->country_id);

                    if ($country->count()) {
                        $country        = $country->first();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // WHAT SHOULD I DO?? tried many thing but they all return as non objects...
            }
            $gender         = Gender::where('id', '=', $user->gender_id);
            if ($gender->count()){
                $gender         = $gender->first();
            } else {
                $gender = [];
            }

            return  View::make('profile.update')
                    ->with('countries', $countries)
                    ->with('country', $country)
                    ->with('city', $city)
                    ->with('address', $address)
                    ->with('gender', $gender)
                    ->with('user', $user);            
        }
        return App::abort(404);
}
```

Here is an example of an input in the update page view.

```
<div class="field">  
            <label for="addressline1">Address line 1</label>                
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="addressline1" {{ (Input::old('addressline1')) ? ' value="' . e(Input::old('addressline1')) . '"' : ' value="' . e($address->addresline1) . '"' }}>
                @if ($errors->has('addressline1'))
                    <div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
                        {{ $errors->first('addressline1') }}
                    </div>
                @endif            
</div>
```

How would you solve that? I feel like there is something super simple to do and I am not seeing it...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all , I suggest you to read [Eloquent Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) again and understand the Relations between models.

If you have One-To-One Relation between your tables. You can use below code.

```
$address = new  Address; //Use in your else block
```

or

```
$address= Auth::user()->address ? : new Address; //For this you have to define Relation
```

Another point ,

```
/*Don't use this*/
$gender         = Gender::where('id', '=', $user->gender_id);

/*Define Relation Between User and Gender Model this is better*/
 $gender = Auth::user()->gender;
```

Finally , best way to do what you are doing is using 'Eager Loading'. For example

```
Auth::user()->with('address.city.country' , 'gender')
```

This code will load User , Adress , City , Country in the same Object.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My relationships are like that: one to one between users and addresses and genders. Cities to addresses = one to many. Countries to cities = one to many

Comment: Then , just use $address = new  Address; in your else block.

Comment: Thanks let me try that tonight! :)